# Referencing different table based on field value

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm trying to design some tables and wondering if I'm missing the correct way to do it. For example, I have a 'main' table (would hold any top level generic info) and I have a field in that table 'type'. Right now I have a different table for each 'type' so I'm using if statements to grab the correct info.

So select * from Main -> then using that type field value to determine which table I need to get my more detailed information from. If type is 1 query TableA... if type is 2 query TableB... etc...

Right now this is working... there is a fixed amount of 'types' but I'm pretty helpless on any nice JOIN statements in this scenario.

Does this make sense? Just seems like I'm doing this a really messed up way.... Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Actually, finally finding some relevant posts... it looks like what I'm doing is like an "enum" type? What are the advantages over that over just using an int? Could I put the tablename as the enum type?

Comment: Dunno how searching didn't bring this up, but the related post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270359/db-design-save-different-details-of-payment-credit-or-check is asking exactly what I am much, much more clearly.
Seems my multiple table approach is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the language you re using, you could generate your SQL dynamically, placing the 'type' table into the dynamic SQL and doing JOINs that way. We do something like this in an application that uses C++, C#, PHP and SQL Server stored procedures, and dynamic SQL is our solution.

Comment: I'm using php/mysql. If something similar exists and just would make my life easier I'd investigate. I'm really just wondering if this is bad design more than anything -- it just doesn't 'feel right'. Seems like I end up with these chained ids all over multiple tables.

Comment: If the post you reference above meets your needs, then by all means go with it. However, if you need dynamic SQL, you can always build your query up as a string with the table name concatenated at run time.