# How to properly create multiple payment methods table in MySQL when more than one method can be applied?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently creating the database schema for a business web app, where multiple payment methods are accepted (Cash, Debit/Credit Card and Bank Transfers), and one can use more than one method for a single transaction in any combination.

Also, people can pay later if he or she is a repeat customer. The main purpose for this schema is to keep track of every payment made for each transaction per method (how many cash, cards, transfers were conducted separately) per week and to keep track of unfinished transactions (due to unfinished transfers or pending payments).

I've also looked at a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270359/db-design-save-different-details-of-payment-credit-or-check) for some insight but I'm not totally sure about the answers since I think those approaches are for a single payment method per transaction.

So far my tables contain these fields:

(I'm not referencing the payment methods to the order table since I'm looking for the right way to do it)

- Orders:

  - id
  - client_id
  - total
  - date
- Cash:

  - id
  - amount
- Terminal: (card details are not necessary, just the reference number of the payment)

  - id
  - amount
  - reference_number
- Transfers:

  - id
  - amount
  - receiving_account (they have multiple bank accounts to receive bank transfers)
  - reference_number
  - transfer_completed (when the transfer funds reaches the destination account)

I'm creating the webpage and database (I'll make the migrations after I finish the DB model) using Laravel + MySQL.

Any help would be deeply appreciated since I'm starting my freelance web developing career and I'm not experienced enough to make things the best way possible.

Edit: Here is my model schema after taking @T.Shah advices

[dbschema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSVJr.png)

PS: English is not my native language so I'm open for grammar suggestions too :)

Comment: Thanks for the grammar corrections @bnahin :)

Comment: All three cash, terminal and transfers tables must contain column order_id which will have the value same as id in Order table. That is how you will be able to relate the information in all these tables.

Comment: Wouldn't be an overkill to use that schema and then joining all the tables for the sales reports? @T.Shah

Comment: If you don't have a column for order I'd, then how will you know the payment method and amount?

Comment: I know that, i'm just wasn't sure about using that method and then joining 3 tables for the amount paid in each transaction, i figured there was a better way to do it